# Reindexing some values in a vector

Tags: matlab

I have this vector of size like 40000 with values like

```
12312345
4564
122356
3455
34566
```

There are like only 200 unique values in this vector. So I want to replace these big values by numbers from 1:200

such that the smallest vector value will be replaced by 1, the next smallest by 2 and so on up to 200.

How can I do it in matlab?

Comment: [~,~,NewVector]=unique(Vector);

Comment: @RTL RTL this guy - rocks (Y)

Answer (score 3):

The third output of unique will do that for you!

```
[~,~,NewVector]=unique(Vector)
```