# Give special indices to the unique elements

Tags: matlab

I have this vector with some random integers. like

```
123234
2344
123234
34
3456
```

What I want to do is find the unique elements in the vector and want to give these elements new values in the range of 1-length of unique elements.

For eg for the above set it will be

```
4
2
4
1
3
```

How can I do it in matlab?

As you can see, I have four unique values, I want to replace the smallest unique value by 1, the second smallest unique value by 2 and so on.

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed?  I do not see how you are arriving at the second set of values.

Comment: @ewz. I have added some details

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from your other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896372/reindexing-some-values-in-a-vector

Comment: @Divakar Agreed. Voting to close. Just use the third output from `unique`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
v = [123234;
2344;
123234;
34;
3456];

u = unique(v);
new_v = zeros(length(v),1);

for ii=1:length(u)
    idx = find(v==u(ii)); 
    new_v(idx) = ii;
end
```

The unique function will return all the unique values, sorted.  You can then step through each sorted value, find where they exist in the original vector, and create a new vector with the loop index as the replacement value.

Looking close at the unique function, it turns out that it already does this for you.  Try this:

```
[ ~, ~, new_v] = unique(v)
```

Comment: I have millions of records. I cannot just loop over, it will take lot of time

Comment: If you read the very last statement, ewz has provided you an alternative that doesn't require any loops.  In addition, have you even tried what ewz has suggested?